# Azure Key Vault - Obtaining Encryption Passphrase

Tags: encryption, azure-keyvault

I have two methods that perform encryption/decryption. These methods accept three parameters ...

1. Plain Text (for encryption) or Cipher Text (for decryption)
2. Initialization Vector
3. Encryption Passphrase

I was planning on using Azure Key Vault to store the Encryption Passphrase but as I read through the documentation it appears as though Azure insists on performing the encryption/decryption itself.

Is there a way to just read the Encryption Passphrase from the Azure Key Vault and use it within my own encryption methods?

Answer (score 3):

You could store it as a secret in the Key Vault.

Encryption/decryption is done by the Key Vault if you're using keys, not secrets.